# Locate unused structures and structure-members

Tags: c, linux, gcc

Some time ago we took over the responsibility of a legacy code base.

One of the quirks of this very badly structured/written code was that
it contained a number of really huge structs, each containing
hundreds of members. One of the many steps that we did was to clean
out as much of the code as possible that wasn't used, hence the need
to find unused structs/struct members.

Regarding the structs, I conjured up a combination of python, [GNU
Global](http://www.gnu.org/software/global/) and [ctags](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/) to list the struct members that are unused.

Basically, what I'm doing is to use `ctags` to generate a tags file,
the python-script below parses that file to locate all struct
members and then using `GNU Global` to do a lookup in the previously
generated global-database to see if that member is used in the code.

This approach have a number of quite serious flaws, but it sort of
solved the issue we faced and gave us a good start for further
cleanup.

There must be a better way to do this!

The question is: How to find unused structures and structure members
in a code base?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
import string
import sys
import operator

def printheader(word):
    """generate a nice header string"""
    print "\n%s\n%s" % (word, "-" * len(word))

class StructFreqAnalysis:
    """ add description"""
    def __init__(self):
        self.path2hfile=''
        self.name=''
        self.id=''
        self.members=[]

    def show(self):
        print 'path2hfile:',self.path2hfile
        print 'name:',self.name
        print 'members:',self.members
        print

    def sort(self):
        return sorted(self.members, key=operator.itemgetter(1))

    def prettyprint(self):
        '''display a sorted list'''
        print 'struct:',self.name
        print 'path:',self.path2hfile
        for i in self.sort():
            print '    ',i[0],':',i[1]
        print

f=open('tags','r')

x={} # struct_name -> class
y={} # internal tags id -> class

for i in f:
    i=i.strip()
    if 'typeref:struct:' in i:
        line=i.split()
        x[line[0]]=StructFreqAnalysis()
        x[line[0]].name=line[0]
        x[line[0]].path2hfile=line[1]
        for j in line:
            if 'typeref' in j:
                s=j.split(':')
                x[line[0]].id=s[-1]
                y[s[-1]]=x[line[0]]

f.seek(0)
for i in f:
    i=i.strip()
    if 'struct:' in i:
        items=i.split()
        name=items[0]
        id=items[-1].split(':')[-1]
        if id:
            if id in y:
                key=y[id]
                key.members.append([name,0])
f.close()

# do frequency count
for k,v in x.iteritems():
    for i in v.members:
        cmd='global -a -s %s'%i[0]     # -a absolute path. use global to give src-file for member
        g=os.popen(cmd)
        for gout in g:
            if '.c' in gout:
                gout=gout.strip()
                f=open(gout,'r')
                for line in f:
                    if '->'+i[0] in line or '.'+i[0] in line:
                        i[1]=i[1]+1
                f.close()

printheader('All structures')
for k,v in x.iteritems():
    v.prettyprint()

#show which structs that can be removed
printheader('These structs could perhaps be removed')
for k,v in x.iteritems():
    if len(v.members)==0:
        v.show()

printheader('Total number of probably unused members')
cnt=0
for k,v in x.iteritems():
    for i in v.members:
        if i[1]==0:
            cnt=cnt+1
print cnt
```

**Edit**

As proposed by @Jens-Gustedt using the compiler is a good way to do it. I'm after a approach that can do a sort of "High Level" filtering before using the compiler-approach.

Comment: What IDE and OS are you using?

Comment: In this case its Linux. No IDE, I use vim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If these are only a few `struct` and if the code does no bad hacks of accessing a `struct` through another type... then you could just comment out all the fields of your first `struct` and let the compiler tell you.

Uncomment one used field after the other until the compiler is satisfied. Then once that compiles, to a good testing to ensure the precondition that there were no hacks.

Iterate over all `struct`.

Definitively not pretty, but at the end you'd have at least one person who knows the code a bit.

Comment: Thats one way to do it, but as I said there are hundreds of members for each struct, the largest one have more than 250 members. This approach would take me a week ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Use [**coverity**](http://www.coverity.com). This is a wonderful tool to detect code flaws, but is a bit costly.

Comment: Do you know what options we should use in Coverity to detect unused elements in a structure? Would it also be reported with an UNUSED_VALUE item?

Answer (score 1):

Although it is a very old post. But recently I did the same using python and gdb. I compiled following snippet of code with structure at the top of hierarchy and then using gdb did print type on the structure and re-cursed into its members.

```
#include <usedheader.h>
UsedStructureInTop *to_print = 0;
int main(){return 0;}

(gdb) p to_print
(gdb) $1 = (UsedStructureInTop *) 0x0
(gdb) pt UsedStructureInTop
type = struct StructureTag {
    members displayed here line by line
}
(gdb)
```

Although my purpose is little different. It is to generate a header that contains only the structure UsedStructureInTop and its dependency types. There are compiler options to do this. But they do not remove unused/unlinked structures found in the included header files.

Comment: Interesting, I'll take a look at this tonight. Meanwhile +1 for the effort :-)

Answer (score 0):

Under C rules, it's possible to access struct members via another structure which has a similar layout. That means that you can access `struct Foo {int a; float b; char c; };` via `struct Bar { int x; float y; };` (except of course for `Foo::c`).

Hence, your algorithm is potentially flawed. It's bloody hard to find what you want, which BTW is why C is hard to optimize.

Comment: My algorithm is very flawed, requires that all member variables have unique names among other things! Thats why I'm asking on SO...